# Server doesn't work (Jboss and aerogear war files)

Tags: jboss, war

hello everyone i was following this tutorial (https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-unifiedpush-server) to have an UnifiedPush server of aerogear so i have download the two .war files and put them in deployments, but when i tried to lunch the server there is n error that i don't understand (sorry if my english is bad).

```
18:10:47,857 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-16) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ag-push: org.jboss.msc.service.Start
Exception in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ag-push: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jboss.aerogear.unifiedpush.keycloak.BootstrapListener.contextInitialized(BootstrapListener.java:40)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:190)
        ... 7 more

18:10:47,863 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "unifiedpush-server-0.11.0.war")
]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ag-push" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deploym
ent.default-server.default-host./ag-push: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
18:10:47,884 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS018559: Deployed "unifiedpush-server-0.11.0.war" (runtime-name : "unifiedpush-server-0.11.0.war")
18:10:47,885 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ag-push: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.def
ault-server.default-host./ag-push: Failed to start service.
```

can anyone help please.

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could build it yourself, using the -Pwildfly maven profile.

Another option is using the docker image:
https://github.com/abstractj/docker/tree/master/aerogear-unifiedpush-dev

Or use the offering for Openshift (you need an OS account, but that is free):
https://github.com/aerogear/openshift-origin-cartridge-aerogear-push